# Double tilde (~~) operator is removing decimal portion of number

Tags: javascript

So all this time I thought I was doing it wrong. But can jQuery read decimals? My first textbox has to multiply the input with .10, the second is .05. But I only get 1 as final result. How can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<head>

<body>

        <input id="first" type="text" />
<script>
        $('#first').on('change', function () {
                $(this).val($(this).val() * .10);
         compute();
        });
</script>

        <input id="second" type="text" />
<script>
        $('#second').on('change', function () {
                $(this).val($(this).val() * .05);
        compute();
        });
</script>

<script>
function compute() {
    var first = ~~$('#first').val();
    var second = ~~$('#second').val();
    var result = $('#result');
    var grade = first + second;
    result.val(grade);
}
</script>

        <input id="result" type="text" readonly />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: show code or you'll be downvoted heavily.

Comment: The `~` operator only works with integers. If you give it a number with a fraction, it ignores the fraction. Why are you using `~~` if you want to keep the fractions?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really have an in-depth knowledge with JS. What should I use to keep the decimals?

Comment: I assume you had some reason for writing `~~$('#first').val()`. If I knew what you were trying to do, I could explain how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to change compute() to this:

```
function compute() {
    var first = parseFloat($('#first').val());
    var second = parseFloat($('#second').val());
    var result = $('#result');
    var grade = first + second;
    result.val(grade);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. That worked just fine. Thanks everyone who entertained my question. Have a nice day!